# Recommendation for Voice Memo Reminder/Alarm Software

Tags: voice-recording, reminders, voice, alarm-clock

All,

Can you please recommend any app/software on either Windows or iPhone, that works as a Reminder/Alarm app but with the Voice Memo. Here are the scenarios.

1. You attend a meeting and there are important notes and action items that need to be taken for next monthly/weekly meeting, but you can't work on it right away. You can either create a text reminder in your Outlook or other apps, but you often forget the context a week after when the alarm/reminder sets in. Easier way would be, to have a short 1-2 minute voice memo, so that you can start right where you left off.
2. Similarly, let's say you want to purchase something, or an idea comes to your mind, but you don't have a time right away to research on it. You set a voice memo with a reminder, so that later you can "pick up your brain" where you left off.

I am aware of Voice Memo app and also reminder apps (they are dime a dozen). And I do not want to type the text and then attach the voice memo. I am looking for a software/app specifically designed for this purpose.

Any suggestions or recommendations. Or any other helpful alternative to this.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "specifically designed"? There are bunch of good regular note taking apps that also have good voice notes support.